# image doesn't change at events

Tags: python, pyqt

I wanted to implement a GUI where the image gets updated each time a keypress event happens, here is an attempt but the image is not updated.

```
class Test(QMainWindow):

 def __init__(self, path):
     super().__init__()
     self.path = path
     self.sliceno = 40
     self.initUI()


 def vol(self):
     slices = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
     return slices


 def keyPressEvent(self, event):
     key = event.key()
     if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Q:  #Event
         self.sliceno = self.sliceno + 1

 def initUI(self):
  
     im = np.uint8(self.vol()[self.sliceno]) #should change the index when 'q' pressed
     qimage = QImage(im, im.shape[1], im.shape[0], QImage.Format_Grayscale8)
     pixmap = QPixmap(qimage)
     pixmap_label.setPixmap(pixmap)

     self.setCentralWidget(pixmap_label)
     self.show()
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the new QPixmap so you have to create a function that updates:

```py
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Q:  # Event
        self.sliceno = self.sliceno + 1
        self.change()

def initUI(self):
    self.pixmap_label = QLabel()
    self.change()
    self.setCentralWidget(self.pixmap_label)
    self.show()

def change(self):
    im = np.uint8(self.vol()[self.sliceno])
    qimage = QImage(im, im.shape[1], im.shape[0], QImage.Format_Grayscale8)
    pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(qimage)
    self.pixmap_label.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

Comment: What if there is a second image? I'd have to create a second function that updates ```change2()``` along with a  ```pixmap2```? is there any example where two image are updated with an event, all using ```QPixmap``` ?  thanks man!